How to display 2D array using MAUI
Tried to write an application with MAUI and got stuck on the simplest task - cannot display a 2D array.
For example:
double[,] my2dArray;
//calculate N and M
my2dArray = new double[N,M];
//populate array with data

Had read TechNet about TableView, ListView, CollectionView with examples, but still no any success. TableView shows only one column even when added several TableSection inside.
Using CollectionView I can set number of columns needed:
collectionView.ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(M, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);

but cannot add any rows after it.

try using a Grid

@Jason TechNet says: "The Grid should not be confused with tables, and is not intended to present tabular data. Unlike HTML tables, a Grid is intended for laying out content. For displaying tabular data, consider using a ListView or CollectionView."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0

I'm not able to get it, can you provide an example, as to what you want as an expected output. I guess you directly want to bind your 2dArray to ItemSource in CollectionView , right? And based on 2d array dimension you want to create rows and columns?

@ShubhamTyagi
it should look like math matrix: https://ibb.co/KVrXPZr
Not necessary, I can transfer elements into control cell by cell if needed. ItemSource accepts only regular 1d arrays.

You can use Grid and then add items Add(Grid, IView, Int32, Int32) at the specified row and column spans.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT thank you Jason already mentioned this solution earlier. But TechNet confuses me by this sentence: "The Grid should not be confused with tables, and is not intended to present tabular data. Unlike HTML tables, a Grid is intended for laying out content. For displaying tabular data, consider using a ListView or CollectionView."

I've experimented with Grid after Jason comment, it was pretty simple to fill it with Labels or Editors, but I still not shure if this is the right solution according to MAUI guidelines.

@AlexJhonson So if you want to use CollectionView and then add rows that grows horizontally as new items are added. You need set ItemsLayoutOrientation.Horizontal  .
